# Diameter comparison: larger, bigger, higher, greater?

Tags: adjectives, comparisons

Which adjective do I use with diameter to compare its size? Is there even one correct answer or is it a style choice?

> The general diameter of veins is [larger|bigger|higher|greater] than that of arteries.

And how do I find such information by myself the next time?

- I checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diameter) which has the following sentence

  > For a convex shape in the plane, the diameter is defined to be the largest distance that can be formed between two opposite parallel
  > lines tangent to its boundary …

  I could deduce from this, that `larger` would be the correct one but
  am not sure if this is logical and why it would be `larger`.
- I then checked [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diameter) and unfortunately the article does not list such an example
- Going by Google result hits

  - `"larger diameter"` 7'420'000 results
  - `"greater diameter" 1'020'000 results
  - `"higher diameter"` 852'000 results
  - `"bigger diameter"` 738'000 results

So after this I would go with `larger` but am not sure why and if this is the correct or best choice.

Edit: Added also `greater` as possiblity as per comment. Did not think of that.

Comment: *Larger* is the best choice here, at least for American English.

Comment: Depends a lot on the context.  Veins or traffic circles?

Comment: @HotLicks ah ok, didn't guess that it matters. Then only for veins as in my example. Might change the question then.

Answer (score 1):

Greater is a useful word. I prefer it in the contexts you mention. Other minor tweaks might help too.

*The general diameter of veins is **greater** than that of arteries.*

*...the diameter is defined as the greatest distance between two opposite parallel lines...*

I would avoid 'bigger', which can sound rather childish, and 'higher', which is best used with numbers or with things that possess actual or figurative height: temperatures, tides etc. Diameters have no height.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice, I would suggest is ***wider***.